# Is it possible to scrape date from a silverlight application like freestockcharts?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, web-crawler, screen-scraping

Is it possible to scrape data off a silverlight application like [freestockcharts](http://www.freestockcharts.com/platform/v1)?

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight is like an app compiled to run under your Browser. Unless you can dissect the Silverlight application from there and extract any kind of API they have in order to retrieve the data, I'm afraid it's not possible by using Javascript alone.